# Manually use R Knit/Markdown to produce plots for HTML

Tags: r, plot, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I am using `knit()`and `markdownToHTML()` to automatically generate reports.

The issue is that I am not outputting plots when using these commands. However, when I use RStudio's `Knit HTML` button, the plots get generated. When I then use my own knit/markdown function, it suddenly outputs the plot. When I switch to another document and knit that one,  the old plot appears.

Example:

````
```{r figA, result='asis', echo=TRUE, dpi=300, out.width="600px", 
              fig=TRUE, fig.align='center', fig.path="figure/"}
plot(1:10)
```
````

Using commands:

```
 knit(rmd, md, quiet=TRUE)
 markdownToHTML(md, html, stylesheet=style)
```

So I guess there are 2 questions, depending on how you want to approach it:

- What magic is going on in Rstudio's `Knit HTML`?
- How can I produce/include without depending on RStudio's `Knit HTML` button?

Comment: I discovered that RStudio outputs them to a folder, while the knitting does not put the plots in this folder.

Comment: Do you mean RStudio outputs plots for _.md_ file in the same directory while `knit()` outputs them into _figure/_ folder? If so, do you know the way to set RStudio output plots to _figure/_ folder without explicitly specifying `opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figure/")` in an _.Rmd_ file?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see here is that this doesn't work when you have the chunk options `{...}` spanning two lines. If it's all on one line, it works fine. Am I missing something?

See how this is not allowed under **knitr** in [the documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options):

> 1. Chunk options must be written in one line; no line breaks are allowed inside chunk options;

RStudio must handle linebreaks in a non-standard way.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it, but have it in that format anyway (the enter here is just for a nicer display). My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is really embarrassing, I really thought I read the documentation carefully:

> include: (TRUE; logical) whether to include the chunk output in the
>   final output document; if include=FALSE, nothing will be written into
>   the output document, but the code is still evaluated and plot files
>   are generated if there are any plots in the chunk, so you can manually
>   insert figures; note this is the only chunk option that is not cached,
>   i.e., changing it will not invalidate the cache

Simply adding `{..., include=TRUE}` did the trick. I would say it would be a pretty sensible default though.